# preg_replace unicode characters

Tags: php, unicode, preg-replace, preg-match

I have several strings which contain unicode. I've been tasked with stripping out everything from these strings except the unicode, so for example, below

```
\ud83d\ude82 + \u2600\ufe0f = \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29
```

would become

```
\ud83d\ude82 \u2600\ufe0f \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29
```

I then need to look for repeating codes, and seperate them so that:

```
 \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29
```

becomes:

```
\ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29
```

I've tried several preg_match solutions for the first bit, but it either doesn't remove any characters from the string, or removes everything. Below is the latest attempt,

```
/(^\\\u[0-9a-f]{4})+/
```

Not being too familiar with Regex, I'm starting to scratch my head in confusion as I'm not really sure what else to try.

This is so that eventually, I'm able to insert each unicode into a database as its own record.

Comment: I think the first step could be done using RegEx. But how to find the repeating codes? You just showed an example instead of describling the rules. For me I think the rule should be grouping the string with each two unicode sub-strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done in two steps:

```
$str = '\ud83d\ude82 + \u2600\ufe0f = \ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29\ud83d\ude29';
// remove non unicode character
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\\\\u[a-f0-9]{4})[^\\\\]+/', '', $str);
// insert space between repeated pair
$str = preg_replace('/((?:\\\u[a-f0-9]{4}){2})(?=\1)/', '$1 ', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
\ud83d\ude82\u2600\ufe0f\ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29 \ud83d\ude29
```

**Regex #1:**

```
/                       : regex delimiter
  (?<=                  : lookahead
    \\\\u[a-f0-9]{4}    : unicode character
  )                     : end lookahead
  [^\\\\]+              : 1 or more any character that is NOT a backslash
/                       : regex delimiter
```

**Regex #2:**

```
/                       : regex delimiter
  (                     : start group 1
    (?:                 : non capture group
      \\\\u[a-f0-9]{4}  : a unicode character
    ){2}                : appears twice (2 unicode characters)
  )                     : end group 1
  (?=\1)                : lookahead, group 1 is repeated
/                       : regex delimiter
```

Comment: This is pretty much perfect! One thing I've noticed though. I have an entry in my database - "\ud83d\udc3e\ud83d\udc36" which is actually 2 separate emoji. Is there anyway to add a space between them in this instance? So you get "\ud83d\udc3e \ud83d\udc36" instead?

Comment: @Jayp: For this specific replacement, you could do: `$str = preg_replace('/(\\\\ud83d\\\\udc3e)(\\\\ud83d\\\\udc36)/', '$1 $2', $str);`